# related to projectile motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, gravity, projectile

I was given this worksheet from my teacher and well im finding it really tough so far ..
the question below is just crushing my skull .. so i would appreciate it if you guys would guide me through it

> A particle projected from ground takes time $t_1$ to reach $\frac{15}{16} H$ and time $t_2$ to cover the rest of distance to the ground. If $H$ is the maximum height attained. find the ratio $\frac{t_1}{t_2}$

well my options were many ... they were $\frac{1}{3}$, $\frac{3}{1}$, $\frac{5}{3}$ and  $\frac{3}{5}$

and well using my knowledge of atleast what i know is:

1. the object has **almost** reached the max height so the ratio wont
   be that big
2. i tried using the equations of motions and to no
   avail i still didnt get anywhere
3. $u \sin(\theta) t_1-\frac{1}{2}g
       (t_1)^2= \frac{15}{16} H$
4. and $\frac{\left(u \sin\theta\right)^2} {2g} =H$

keeping in mind that $t_2$ has to obviously be greater than $t_1$ ... the second and the third options are eliminated ... well it surely cant be $\frac{1}{3}$(maybe) .. because that is a really big ratio ...

is there some other extra formula or something other than the common formulae (like max height and range and splitting of vectors)i am supposed to know to solve this question
am i missing out anything?

Comment: Hmm, the exact same question got posted a few minutes ago and closed. Now show how you arrived at these equations, and fix the units on equation 4.

Comment: @ja72 well i didnt understand your query could you please elaborate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Total time taken by the projectile, $$T=\frac{2u\sin\theta}{g}$$
So $$t_{2}=T-t_{1}$$
Solve for $t_{1}$ putting $H=\frac{\left(u \sin\theta\right)^2} {2g}$ in the quadratic equation. You will get two roots. With those values you will find out $t_{2}$. Actually, you will get two $t_{2}$'s, hence two ratios. Infact one will the inverse of the other. You will get two correct answers.
I think this hint is sufficient to answer your question.

Comment: is this correct?

Comment: cuz i think i was just mindblown

Comment: What? you will definitely get two answers.

Comment: Go ahead with this. I don't see any difficulty.

Comment: which equation should i put H=(usinthetha)^2/2g in?

Comment: "in the quadractic equation" ..which one

Comment: You marked it with a 3.

Comment: ok so let me get this straight put value of H in 3) and then solve for t right?

Comment: Yeah, that's right

Comment: @pratyash is there any other way to solve it? like these questions come for iit and it is supposed to take less time to solve ..